# Can't play 1080p mkv videos in default video player or in vlc

Tags: 20.04, video, vlc, video-player, mkv

I have downloaded ubuntu restricted extras, but I can't play the video file which is in 1080p mkv on my laptop.
In vlc player only audio plays and in default video player audio & video both laggs
My laptop is lenovo IdeaPad 110.
What to do??

Comment: Please define "can't play". What happens exactly?

Comment: Can you view that exact file on other systems?  It might have broken in transit.

Comment: Files work fine on my android phone, I don't think file might broken in transit